Mapbox queryRenderedFeatures detecting features offset from point provided at some zoom levels
I have a mapbox app that plots points on a map and lets the user hover to reveal additional info. To detect hover state, I'm using a mousemove event + queryRenderedFeatures, but the event's lngLat doesn't always correspond to the mouse cursor's apparent position. It appears to happen at intermediate zoom levels (approximately zoom "6"), where the map is in halfway between the zoomed-in flat projection and the zoomed-out "globe" view. Setting the map projection to "mercator" prevents the offset from occurring, but I prefer to keep the default "globe" view if possible.
I built this debug app to show the offset visually. Mousing over the red dots in the grid should cause a popup to appear. The green-and-red circle shows the mousemove event's point.lngLat coordinates. The green-and-red circle does not track my cursor precisely, which makes it hard to select a specific dot.
Is there any way to fix the offset, while still using "globe" projection?
https://jsfiddle.net/jackcarter/15q8xpjg/4/

